# Metal detector using Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

Is anyone out there building serious metal detectors with the Arduino? By "serious" I mean metal detectors with phase sensitivity to discriminate between ferrous and non-ferrous metals, etc.  Seems like the Uno is a good platform for a smart metal detector project.

Update: 
Arduino allows me to control phase discrimination which allows ferrous metals to be rejected.
I already know it can be done with an analog phase shift circuit.
Also Arduino can perform target ID function with readout to 16x2 LCD display.

Comment: Should be possible with only analog logic. I don't see where you'd need an arduino. Just google some schematics for metal detectors.

Answer (score 1):

A set of posts on Instructables uses an Arduino Nano to generate a Phase Induction pulse, with a capacitor instead of a dump resistor to set up a decaying oscillation, which is then limited with diodes and detected by the analog comparator with interrupts.  The comparator interrupts then count the frequency of the decaying ringing oscillation producing some ferrous/non-ferrous discrimination, and the duration of the ringing, producing some signal strength and size information.

- Nano doing Pulse induction with LC-trap oscillation: https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Based-Pulse-Induction-Detector-LC-Trap/
- Nano meta detection software with high-frequency ADC sampling: https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Program-an-Arduino-Based-Metal-Detector/
- Nano doing Pulse Induction, shifting the recovery pulse to match the arduino's analog comparator: https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Based-Pulse-Induction-Detector/

The tricks in the Pulse Induction LC-trap system of using the analog comparator would be applicable to detecting phase shifts and detecting crossings in sync with a timer-based output.